# How do I combine Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I try to combine multiple promises in a nodejs application. But in each attempt I get no result.

If the database is not created, the function `checkForDataTable` will not call but the database is created. If I call the `initDatabase` again, the database will not created again (thats fine) and the datatable is created.

Why on the scond start, not on the first?

Please help me to find the mistakes. THX

```
function initDatabase(){
   return checkForDatabase(dbName)
          .then(checkForDataTable);
}

function checkForDatabase(databaseName){
    return server.list()
           .then((databases) => {
               if(databaseExists(databases, databaseName)){
                   return database();
               } else {
                   return server
                          .create(...)
                          .then((database) => {
                              return database;
                          });
               }
           });
}

function checkForDataTable(database){
    return database.tables.list()
           .then((tables) => {
               if(dataTableExist(tables, tableName)){
                  return // this specific datatable
               } else {
                  return database.tables.create(tableName)
                         .then((dataTable) => {
                             return dataTable;
                         });
               }
           });
}

function database() {
    return server.use(...); // this is a promise
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep your promises, don't go into politics.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to do `.then((x) => return x);` the promise already has that value.

Comment: also `(x) => { return x; }` can/should be written `(x) => x`

Comment: does `server.create(...)` return a promise of a value that is the same as the promise of a value that is returned by `server.use(...)` - your code implies it does - the main issue I have with your code is that it is too incomplete, there's no indication of how the function database can possibly know which database you are trying to use as it has no arguments, the var tableName seems to be a global or something ... code is just too abstract to provide a decent answer

Comment: `Promise.all` probably.

Comment: @SLaks @Jaromanda-X Thanks for the hint. I have shrink my code from original. In any function is also a `logger.info(...)`, so i think I need the `return`. Neverthless thanks.

@Jaromanda-X yes the `server.create(...)` returns a promise.

The arguments to `create` or `use`the database coming from configuration or ´const´.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is important that

```
server.use(...)
```

is called in your `database()` function. This only happens when the database is already present.

Try to do it as well right after the creation of the database:

```
function checkForDatabase(databaseName){
    return server.list()
       .then((databases) => {
           if(databaseExists(databases, databaseName)){
               return database();
           } else {
               return server
                      .create(...)
                      .then((db) => { // Change param name or remove it
                          return database(); // so you can make this call
                      });
           }
       })
}
```

**Update:** If this does not help, I suggest you restructure the code. I see three steps here. Creating the database if it does not exist, using the database (`server.use(...)`) and creating the table if it does not exist. I think this should be reflected in your code more clearly:

```
function initDatabase(){
    return assertDatabaseExists(databaseName) // former check for database
        .then(function() {
            return server.use(/* databaseName? */); // replaces database() function
        })
        .then(function(database) {
            assertTableExists(database); // former checkForDataTable
        });
}
```

The individual functions should be slightly simpler and I think debugging will also be simpler, so you can narrow down on the actual problem.

Comment: Thx, it looks simple, but does not help. The behaviour is the same. In my original code I have some log infos for tracing the function calls. The log says that your solution is the same like before. :-(

I have no idea why.

Is it possible the promise decides between the return values. In case of database not exists it returns a promise and otherwise it returns the database. My be here is the failure?

Comment: In a function passed to then as a success handler it makes no difference whether you return a value or a promise resolving to that value, at least from the caller's point of view.

Comment: @jan-fellien, I updated my answer with a suggestion how to track down the problem.

Comment: your update looks very well. I giv it a try.
In your opinion the `assertDatabaseExists` function creates the database if not exists, right?

Comment: yes, correct. basically it does the same as your old function but it does not return anything. As I see it in your code, the return value is not really used because you call your `database()` function anyway without parameter and use its return value.

Comment: unfortunately this refactoring is not the solution yet. I'll try some completely different. Thx for your support